# How to run unit tests written with Microsoft Moles without installing it?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moles

Our team is working on writing unit tests for a big .Net project, using “Visual Studio 2010” IDE and “NUnit” (v. 2.5.9) unit-testing framework. Also we use “Microsoft Moles” type-isolating framework. After we finished writing tests for specific module we have to build all the modules and run unit tests on different machine where the Moles is not installed.

Is it possible to run unit tests written with moles without actually installing moles framework but only by copying and/or registering (in GAC or in System Registry) specific components? And if so, what are these components?

---

For example, we have found out that it needs to register “Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.ClrMonitor.x86” in the Windows registry in order to run unit tests.

Comment: This is definitely something I'm interested in. It would be easier to bring up new CI build agents with a non-install answer.

Comment: Given enough time, you should probably be able to do it, but what's the point here? If you want to manually perform the steps that the Moles set-up does, why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can given the complexity of the setup. There 79 files going to 49 directories. It's a platform component, you just need to have it as a prereq just like having .NET.